# Getting return value from Javascript in WebKit / JavaScriptCore

Tags: javascript, webkit, javascriptcore

I am using the JavaScriptCore API in order to obtain a global context to Javascript. I would like to be able to manipulate the value I get back from Javascript in C. Here is the code sample I have that is relevant:

```
JSGlobalContextRef jsContext = webkit_web_frame_get_global_context(webkit_web_view_get_main_frame(webView));

JSStringRef script = JSStringCreateWithUTF8CString("ReturnOne()");

JSValueRef val = JSEvaluateScript(jsContext, script, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL);

return JSValueToNumber(jsContext, val, NULL);
```

ReturnOne() is a JavaScript function that looks like this:

```
function ReturnOne() {
  return 1;
}
```

When I put an alert in the function, it displays, so I know the function is being called correctly. I am trying to simply print out the number 1 but I get a large negative value instead. Am I not interpreting JSValueToNumber correctly?

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: I have done some digging around and found this gem - https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-help/2011-January/001849.html

Unfortunately, I get the same result implementing my C code in this fashion. My function in Javascript is returning a primitive and I would like to convert that Javascript primitive into the value I'm expecting (in this case, 1).

I would also be okay with an alternative in which an object is returned from Javascript, so long as I can get the numeric value I expect.

Answer (score 0):

it seems ok. but maybe you should put ; to end of `ReturnOne()`.

and maybe you should cast returned value to int. because, it returns double and your print function accepts int value.

I dont try, but it should look like,

```
JSStringRef script = JSStringCreateWithUTF8CString("ReturnOne();");
JSValueRef val = JSEvaluateScript(jsContext, script, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL);
return (int)JSValueToNumber(jsContext, val, NULL);
```